# politely remind a professor about editing an article

Tags: grammar

How do I politely remind a professor about editing an article? Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

*I know how busy you are but I very would like to have your valuable contribution and comments  in this article before submit it. Could you please let me know that do your schedule allow to review article?*

Comment: _...I would very much like to have your valuable contribution and comments on this article ...  know when your schedule allows you to..._

Comment: 'I very would like to have' is not idiomatic English. But I wish it were. I like the sound of it.

Answer (score 1):

I know how busy you are but I would **really** like to have your valuable contribution and comments in this article before submit**ting** it. Could you please let me know **whether** you are available to review the article or not?